# Advanced CSS Selector - Select based on styling

Tags: css, css-selectors

Performance issues aside, is it possible to use a style as a selector? For example, something like:

```
div[background-image="img/someimg.jpg"] {opacity:.5}
```

My fallback plan is to use javascript and iterate over divs (adding a class when found), but this might end up being even *more* expensive given that the page is highly dynamic, and I'm not in control of the divs being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [W3C page on Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

> CSS 2.1 allows authors to specify rules that match elements which have certain attributes defined in the source document.

Attributes are the things defined from the HTML code itself, like `id`, `class`, `src`, `href`, etc.:

```
<a id="foo" href="bar">Foo</a>
```

Unless you specifically defined the style from within a `style` attribute, like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('img/someimg.jpg');">Foo</div>
```

You can't do anything with CSS.

If you *did* do it inline, you could try this selector:

```
div[style="background-image: url('img/someimg.jpg');"]
{
  /* ... */
}
```

Now that you're worried about performance, you can try using pure-JS to do this (untested):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
  var current = divs[i];

  if (current.style.backgroundImage == "url('img/someimg.jpg')")
  {
    current.style.opacity = 0.5; // You'll need more hacks for IE...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I'm actually trying to work with html generated from an API, wherein the styles are inline, and there are a ton of them. I don't think the attribute selector will work, given that I don't know what *other* styles they're going to jam in there.

Comment: @Matrym see my answer below which solves this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45746014/8047

Answer (score 11):

Even if there are a lot of styles, you can do this by using the asterisk as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426901/8047), so this code:

```
div[style*="box-sizing: border-box;"] {
   background-color: #ffffe0;
}
```

easily matches this HTML:

```
<div style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 8px; font-family: Monaco, Menlo, Consolas, " courier="" new",="" monospace;="" font-size:="" 12px;="" color:="" rgb(51,="" 51,="" 51);="" border-top-left-radius:="" 4px;="" border-top-right-radius:="" border-bottom-right-radius:="" border-bottom-left-radius:="" background-color:="" rgb(251,="" 250,="" 248);="" border:="" 1px="" solid="" rgba(0,="" 0,="" 0.14902);="" background-position:="" initial="" initial;="" background-repeat:="" initial;-en-codeblock:true;"=""><div><font style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="line-height: normal; font-family: Monaco; font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures; color: rgb(54, 86, 138);">func</span><span style="line-height: normal; font-family: Monaco; font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"> doThis(thing: </span><span style="line-height: normal; font-family: Monaco; font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures; color: rgb(195, 89, 0);">AnyObject</span><span style="line-height: normal; font-family: Monaco; font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">) {</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Monaco;">}</span></font></div>
<div><font style="font-size: 14px;"><br></font></div>
<div><font style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-variant-caps: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Monaco; font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures; color: rgb(54, 86, 138);">func</span><span style="font-variant-caps: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Monaco; font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"> doThisThing(thing thing: </span><span style="font-variant-caps: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Monaco; font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures; color: rgb(195, 89, 0);">AnyObject</span><span style="font-variant-caps: normal; line-height: normal; font-family: Monaco; font-variant-ligatures: no-common-ligatures; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">) {</span><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Monaco;">}</span></font></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest manipulating CSS classes rather than individual styles in this case. For example:

```
div.some-img
{
    background-image: url('img/someimg.jpg');
}

div.some-img-fade
{
    opacity: 5;
}
```

......

```
$('div.some-img').each(function() { $(this).addClass('some-img-fade'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's something called DOMSubtreeModified which has now been turned into `MutationObserver`. This can help you watch the dom for when new elements are added:

```
// identify an element to observe
var elementToObserve = document.querySelector("#targetElementId");

// create a new instance of `MutationObserver` named `observer`, 
// passing it a callback function
var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
    console.log('callback that runs when observer is triggered');
});

// call `observe` on that MutationObserver instance, 
// passing it the element to observe, and the options object
observer.observe(elementToObserve, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

This example is copy/pasted from mdn docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe