# How can I replace text with CSS?

Tags: css, text, replace

How can I replace text with CSS using a method like this:

```
.pvw-title img[src*="IKON.img"] { visibility:hidden; }
```

Instead of  (  `img[src*="IKON.img"]`  ), I need to use something that can replace text instead.

I have to use `[`  `]` to get it to work.

`<div class="pvw-title">Facts</div>`

I need to replace "**Facts**".

Comment: The question is how to do it with CSS. I **am** using a CMS that only allows me to change the CSS, which is why I arrived at **this** page while googling for the answer, and not a different one. That is why we answer the question that was asked instead of asking why the asker's situation isn't different.

Comment: If anybody else is as clueless as I am: [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Answer (score 418):

Or maybe you could wrap 'Facts' round a `<span>` as follows:

```css
.pvw-title span {
  display: none;
}
.pvw-title:after {
  content: 'whatever it is you want to add';
}
```

```html
<div class="pvw-title"><span>Facts</span></div>
```

Comment: Nice, but that's a change to HTML rather than just CSS.

Comment: Sometimes its your only option

Comment: How can I include a new line? Tried <br> and \n without success. Thanks

Comment: span { display: none; } should also hide the pseudo element. You should use visibility: hidden instead

Comment: display: none; and visibility: hidden; both hide the pseudo element

Comment: @Mathew is hiding the span but adding the pseudo element to the div, so the pseudo element should not be hidden (either by using visibility or display property)

Comment: If you're changing the HTML then you should probably change the text in the HTML itself.

Comment: This is the only approach that works for my situation so far. I have control over the HTML and CSS, but I only want to replace some label text within a longer line of text for one particular customer and this is in fact the tidiest approach.

Comment: This approach is also good if you want to include help text for a file upload input, as the wording on the button is different in Chrome to IE and Firefox. Rather than hacking the input file element you can simply target the help text this way.

Comment: I believe, there should be `::after` instead of `:after`

Answer (score 332):

**Obligatory**: This is a hack: CSS isn't the right place to do this, but in some situations - eg, you have a third party library in an iframe that can only be customized by CSS - this kind of hack is the only option.

You can replace text through CSS. **Let's replace a green button that has the word 'hello' with a red button that has the word 'goodbye'**, using CSS.

### Before

Here's our green button:

```css
button {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
```

### After

Now let's hide the original element, but add another block element afterwards:

```css
button {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Bonus CSS to do cool things */

button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
button:after {
  content:'goodbye'; 
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello</button>
```

Note:

- We explicitly need to mark this as a block element, 'after' elements are inline by default
- We need to compensate for the original element by adjusting the pseudo-element's position.
- We must hide the original element and display the pseudo element using `visibility`. Note `display: none` on the original element doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't work in ie 10, any idea how to modify it to do so?

Comment: `display: none;` doesn’t work because `::after` really means “inside this element, but at the end”, in case anyone was curious.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "modified" button does not work like a button anymore. It's a good example, just that it does not apply to a button.

Comment: display: none; and visibility: hidden; both hide the pseudo element

Comment: How come when I do this it replaces the element but the text is all caps and can't be changed to lowercase?

Comment: @JpajiRajnish That's probably because you need to set it to `text-transform: lowercase`.

Comment: @JpajiRajnish What browser? Replaced text is 'goodbye' here, all lowercase.

Comment: so you can only use `content:` css on pseudo elements?
is it possible to add a `:focus` box-shadow on a pseudo element?

Comment: Indeed this hack is not universal. You have to take into account that the resulting element will retain the dimensions of the original element. So your replacement text should be the same width/height.

Answer (score 218):

If you're willing to use pseudo elements and let them insert content, you can do the following. It doesn't assume knowledge of the original element and doesn't require additional markup.

```
.element {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  line-height: 0; /* Collapse the original line */
}

.element::after {
  content: "New text";
  text-indent: 0;
  display: block;
  line-height: initial; /* New content takes up original line height */
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jvandyke/U52Tt/)

Comment: This answer works in places that a number of the other answers don't such as text nodes inside a `<th>` element.

Comment: This works well. In my case, `line-height: 0` and `color: transparent` on the main element and resetting those values on the pseudo do the job (no fiddling with `text-indent`)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `line-height: normal` instead of `initial`?

Comment: the reason to use text-indent is that if the original text is longer, the element remains the size of the old text, not shrinking to the size of the new text (assuming that is what you want)

Comment: The text-indent: -9999px; works on IE. Whereas the visibility: hidden; method doesn't work on IE.

Comment: This works for me inside of a th element but not on a label element, Any ideas why?. In the last case I added visibility hidden/visible

Comment: This solution is best because it works in Internet explorer.

Comment: This is easily the best answer!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the effect on accessibility of this solution? Will screen-readers see both text elements squished together?

Comment: It should be noted that the example assumes that the element is the block one. For example, it does not work for elements with `display: inline`.

Answer (score 89):

Based on
[mikemaccana’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14261898),
this worked for me

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

button:before {
  content: "goodbye";
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button>original</button>
```

[§ Absolute positioning](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus
> takes up no space when placing other elements.

Comment: For me this answer was superior to others because it works with a text replacement within the same line, that is, it does not force a line break in text (for my particular combination of HTML and CSS).

Answer (score 44):

This is simple, short, and effective. No additional HTML is necessary.

```
.pvw-title { color: transparent; }

.pvw-title:after {
        content: "New Text To Replace Old";
        color: black; /* set color to original text color */
        margin-left: -30px;
        /* margin-left equals length of text we're replacing */
    }
```

I had to do this for replacing link text, other than home, for [WooCommerce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WooCommerce) breadcrumbs

#### [Sass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29)/[Less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29)

```
body.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb > a[href$="/shop/"] {
    color: transparent;
    &:after {
        content: "Store";
        color: grey;
        margin-left: -30px;
    }
}
```

#### CSS

```
body.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb > a[href$="/shop/"] {
    color: transparent;
}

body.woocommerce .woocommerce-breadcrumb > a[href$="/shop/"]&:after {
    content: "Store";
    color: @child-color-grey;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 36):

In order to use after and hide the original content, you can use this hack:

```css
.pvw-title {
  font-size: 0;
}
.pvw-title:after {
  font-size: 1rem;
  content: 'I am a totally different piece of text!';
}
```

```html
<div class="pvw-title">Facts</div>
```

Setting `font-size` to 0 makes the text disappear without removing the actual element from the viewport. Therefore, the `:after` selector works and should show on all browsers.

Answer (score 28):

You can't, well, you can.

```
.pvw-title:after {
  content: "Test";
}
```

This will insert content *after* the current content of the element. It doesn't actually replace it, but you can choose for an empty div, and use CSS to add all the content.

But while you more or less can, you shouldn't. Actual content should be put in the document. The content property is mainly intended for small markup, like quotation marks around text that should appear quoted.

Comment: I'm very sure about that I used a code to replace text with kind of that method..

'<div class="pvw-title">Facts</div>
<div class="pvw-title">Facts</div>'

I can't use :after, cause i got more than one div class with the same name :(

Comment: How widely compatible is that for browsers? And i suspect javascript is going to be a better choice long term for this kind of flexibility.

Comment: Modern browsers support it. I'm not sure about older IE versions, but I guess that can be looked up on quirksmode.com. -edit- It can: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/content.html

Answer (score 15):

Try using `:before` and `:after`. One inserts text after HTML is rendered, and the other inserts before HTML is rendered. If you want to replace text, leave button content empty.

This example sets the button text according to the size of the screen width.

```css
button:before {
  content: 'small screen';
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  button:before {
    content: 'big screen';
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<button type="button">xxx</button>
<button type="button"></button>
```

Button text:

1. With `:before`

   big screenxxx

   big screen
2. With `:after`

   xxxbig screen

   big screen

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way I found is by making the element `font-size: 0px`, then overwrite it with any font size when creating `:after` pseudo. Example below:

```
.pvw-title { 
    font-size:0px;
}

.pvw-title:after {
        content: "Hello";
        font-size:15px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to show different texts or images, **keep the tag empty and write your content in multiple data attributes** like that `<span data-text1="Hello" data-text2="Bye"></span>`.
Display them with one of the pseudo classes `:before {content: attr(data-text1)}`

Now you have a bunch of different ways to switch between them. I used them in combination with media queries for a responsive design approach to change the names of my navigation to icons.

[jsfiddle demonstration and examples](https://jsfiddle.net/70m08tev/)

<sub>*It may not perfectly answer the question, but it satisfied my needs and maybe others too.*</sub>

Answer (score 12):

I had better luck setting the `font-size: 0` of the outer element, and the `font-size` of the `:after` selector to whatever I needed.

Comment: This works well. [Here is a demo](https://codepen.io/arthurattwell/pen/KbXNKE?editors=1100).

Comment: Smart use of font-size:0 - first time for me. Kudos!

Answer (score 12):

#### Text replacement with pseudo-elements and CSS visibility

HTML

```
<p class="replaced">Original Text</p>
```

CSS

```
.replaced {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.replaced:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "This text replaces the original.";
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this way:

```
IDENTIFIER {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
IDENTIFIER::after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "NEW_CONTENT";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the element is center aligned or not at the start of its bounding box

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me with inline text. It was tested in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, and Opera.

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur <span>Some Text</span> adipiscing elit.</p>

span {
    visibility: hidden;
    word-spacing: -999px;
    letter-spacing: -999px;
}

span:after {
    content: "goodbye";
    visibility: visible;
    word-spacing: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in at least IE 9 through 11 due to it ignoring the "visibility:visible" on the :after element: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530947/ie10-visibilityvisible-on-before-pseudo-element-of-visibilityhidden-eleme

Answer (score 9):

I use this trick:

```
.pvw-title {
    text-indent: -999px;
}
.pvw-title:after {
    text-indent: 0px;
    float: left;
    content: 'My New Content';
}
```

I've even used this to handle internationalization of pages by just changing a base class...

```
.translate-es .welcome {
    text-indent: -999px;
}
.translate-es .welcome:after {
    text-indent: 0px;
    float: left;
    content: '¡Bienvenidos!';
}
```

Comment: This is problematic for users with screen readers.  If you don't change the disaply/visibility of the element and don't provide any aria hints, your "invisible" text may still be read by a screen reader.

Answer (score 3):

Using a pseudo element, this method doesn't require knowledge of the original element and doesn't require any additional markup.

```
#someElement{
    color: transparent; /* You may need to change this color */
    position: relative;
}
#someElement:after { /* Or use :before if that tickles your fancy */
    content: "New text";
    color: initial;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This implements a checkbox as a button which shows either Yes or No depending on its 'checked' state.  So it demonstrates one way of replacing text using CSS without having to write any code.

It will still behave like a checkbox as far as returning (or not returning) a POST value, but from a display point of view it looks like a toggle button.

The colours may not be to your liking, they're only there to illustrate a point.

The HTML is:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="yesno" id="testcb" /><label for="testcb"><span></span></label>
```

...and the CSS is:

```
/* --------------------------------- */
/* Make the checkbox non-displayable */
/* --------------------------------- */
input[type="checkbox"].yesno {
    display:none;
}
/* --------------------------------- */
/* Set the associated label <span>   */
/* the way you want it to look.      */
/* --------------------------------- */
input[type="checkbox"].yesno+label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    color:#800000;
    background-color:white;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:black;
    cursor:pointer;
}
/* --------------------------------- */
/* By default the content after the  */
/* the label <span> is "No"          */
/* --------------------------------- */
input[type="checkbox"].yesno+label span:after {
    content:"No";
}
/* --------------------------------- */
/* When the box is checked the       */
/* content after the label <span>    */
/* is "Yes" (which replaces any      */
/* existing content).                */
/* When the box becomes unchecked the*/
/* content reverts to the way it was.*/
/* --------------------------------- */
input[type="checkbox"].yesno:checked+label span:after {
    content:"Yes";
}
/* --------------------------------- */
/* When the box is checked the       */
/* label <span> looks like this      */
/* (which replaces any existing)     */
/* When the box becomes unchecked the*/
/* layout reverts to the way it was. */
/* --------------------------------- */
input[type="checkbox"].yesno:checked+label span {
    color:green;
    background-color:#C8C8C8;
}
```

I've only tried it on Firefox, but it's standard CSS so it ought to work elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution like this where a word, "Dark", would be shortened to just "D" on a smaller screen width. Basically you just make the font size of the original content 0 and have the shortened form as a pseudo element.

In this example the change happens on hover instead:

```css
span {
  font-size: 12px;
}

span:after {
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  content: 'D';
  color: red;
}

span:hover {
  font-size: 0px;
}

span:hover:after {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<span>Dark</span>
```

Comment: FINALLY. I had to work around the `:hover` business you had going on, and also had to add `line-height: 0px` alongside the `font-size: 0px` on the original element, but this is the *ONLY* answer that doesn't mess up padding/spacing/surrouding elements/the container element for me. Credited you in my derivative answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76243509/3511695

Answer (score 2):

Setting the original element's `line-height` and `font-size` to `0px` (then setting the `:after` pseudo element's `font-size`) is the *only* thing that worked for me without messing up spacing/formatting/padding of the element's container and surrounding elements.

```css
#test {
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}

#test:after {
  font-size: 12px;
  content: 'Good Bye';
}
```

```html
<span id="test">Hello</span>
```

*Built off [StefanBob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59514901/3511695)'s answer.*

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where I had to replace the text of link, but I couldn't use JavaScript nor could I directly change the text of a hyperlink as it was compiled down from XML. Also, I couldn't use pseudo elements, or they didn't seem to work when I had tried them.

Basically, I put the text I wanted into a span and put the anchor tag underneath it and wrapped both in a div. I basically moved the anchor tag up via CSS and then made the font transparent. Now when you hover over the span, it "acts" like a link. A really hacky way of doing this, but this is how you can have a link with different text...

[This is a fiddle of how I got around this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/s288asct/)

My HTML

```
<div class="field">
    <span>This is your link text</span><br/>
    <a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">This is your actual link</a>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
 div.field a {
     color: transparent;
     position: absolute;
     top:1%;
 }
 div.field span {
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

The CSS will need to change based off your requirements, but this is a general way of doing what you are asking.

Comment: @AlmightWhy I suspect this was downvoted because this solution requires modifying the markup and I suspect if the OP could modify the markup, he/she would just change the text directly. In other words, the OP required a CSS only solution

Answer (score 1):

Unlike what I see in every single other answer, you *don't need* to use pseudo elements in order to replace the content of a tag with an image

```
<div class="pvw-title">Facts</div>

    div.pvw-title { /* No :after or :before required */
        content: url("your URL here");
    }
```

Comment: As of CSS2, `content` only applies to `:before` and `:after`. CSS3 extends it to everything, but the Generated Content module is still in draft status, so any use is *highly* likely to be browser-dependent.

Comment: What is a *"balise"*? Not *"[1. (European Train Control System) An electronic beacon or transponder placed between the rails of a railw](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/balise#Noun)"*, I presume. (Please respond by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45248211/edit), not here in comments).)

Answer (score 1):

After eight years, I faced the same challenge when trying to use the [Stylish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish) browser extension to change something on a website (not mine). And this time I made it work by looking at the source code using "inspect element" and created the CSS code based on that.

This it what it looked like before:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td role="gridcell">
        <span title="In progress" style="background-color: #e2047a;color:White;margin:2px;border-radius:2px;padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;text-align: center;width: 45px; display: block;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">In progress</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the same piece of the HTML and the CSS I used to modify the style:

```css
td span[style="background-color: #e2047a;color:White;margin:2px;border-radius:2px;padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;text-align: center;width: 45px; display: block;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"] {
  width: 100px!important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td role="gridcell">
        <span title="In progress" style="background-color: #e2047a;color:White;margin:2px;border-radius:2px;padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;text-align: center;width: 45px; display: block;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;">In progress</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can run the code above and you will see that it works (tested in Chrome).

---

<sub>This is simply what I wanted back in the days when I asked this question.</sub>

<sub>I was using some sort of community blog/[Myspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myspace) similar stuff and the only thing you had when styling your profile was their CSS editor, and that's why I wanted to select it based on the style.</sub>

I found the answer here:

- *[Advanced CSS Selector - Select based on styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535193/advanced-css-selector-select-based-on-styling)*
- *[CSS selector by inline style attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426882/css-selector-by-inline-style-attribute?noredirect=1&lq=1)*

Answer (score 1):

Well, as many said this is a hack. However, I'd like to add more up-to-date hack, which takes an advantage of `flexbox` and `rem`, i.e.

- You don't want to manually position this text to be changed, that's why you'd like to take an advantage of `flexbox`
- You don't want to use `padding` and/or `margin` to the text explicitly using `px`, which for different screen sizes on different devices and browsers might give different output

Here's the solution, in short `flexbox` makes sure that it's automatically positioned perfectly and `rem` is more standardized (and automated) alternative for pixels.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/a-hack-how-to-replace-html-text-using-css-x6xeo) with code below and output in a form of a screenshot, do please read a `note` below the code!

```
h1 {
  background-color: green;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
h1:after {
  background-color: silver;
  color: yellow;
  content: "This is my great text AFTER";
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: -2.3rem;
  visibility: visible;
}
h1:before {
  color: blue;
  content: "However, this is a longer text to show this example BEFORE";
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: -2.3rem;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Note: for different tags you might need different values of `rem`, this one has been justified for `h1` and only on large screens. However with `@media` you could easily extend this to mobile devices.

[image: A hack how to replace HTML text using CSS]

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <title>Devnote</title>
    <style>
        .replacedValue { 
            visibility: hidden; 
            position: relative; 
        } 
        .replacedValue:after { 
            visibility: visible; 
            position: absolute; 
            top: 0; 
            left: 0; 
            content: "Devnote is developer answer solve. devnote.in"; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head>
<body> 
    <p class="replacedValue">Old Text Here</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Output**

```
Devnote is developer answer solve. devnote.in
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really possible without tricks. Here is a way that works by replacing the text with an image of text.

```
.pvw-title{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background-image: url(text_image.png)
}
```

This type of thing is typically done with JavaScript. Here is how it can be done with jQuery:

```
$('.pvw-title').text('new text');
```

Comment: I can't use Javascript either :/

Comment: This is the only way I think it could work:

.pvw-title span[style*="color:#000, font-size:14px;"]{
    visibility:hidden;
}

.pvw-title span[style*="color:#000; font-size:14px;"]: after{
    visibility:visible;
    color:#000;
    font-size:14px;
    content: "Test";
}

but, since they both using the same style, I can't do it.. :/

Comment: why would you select it based on the color/font?

Comment: I would you select it based on the whole style, so I can edit that specific title and not both, since the both have the same "div" name.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make this work is to add line-height to the CSS content. This will make the block to be seen above the hidden, thus this will not hide the changed text.

Example with use **before**:

```
.pvw-title span {
  display: none;
}

.pvw-title:before {
  content: 'Whatever it is you want to add';
  line-height: 1.5em
}
```