# In CSS use "display:none" on the element, but keep its ":after"

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to not display an element, as with *display:none*, but continue to display the *:before* and/or *:after*?

I tried

```
#myspan       {display:none}
#myspan:after {display:inline; content:"*"}
```

but that didn't work. I'm trying to have CSS replace the content of a span with an asterisk, without introducing jQuery.

Comment: "but that didn't work" -- what did happen then? Neither is visible?

Comment: That's right. Neither is visible.

Comment: I tried setting `content` on the element itself but that didn't work either (no effect): http://jsfiddle.net/saJWC/

Comment: I'm afraid you need javascript.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Pseudo elements are rendered like children:

```
<span id="myspan">whatever<after></span>
```

And `display:none` hides the element including all children.

#### EDIT 1

JavaScript is your best option in my opinion. Even without jQuery changing text is not hard:

```
document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML = "*";​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2jgj2/1/)

#### EDIT 2

However, if you really want to do it with CSS, you can use negative `text-indent` to hide the text and `relative` positioning to show the asterisk:

```
#myspan {    
    text-indent: -9999px;
    display: block;
}

#myspan:before {
    content: '*';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 9999px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2jgj2/2/)

​

Comment: What do you suggest as a means to replace an element content?

Comment: `<span class="asterisk"><span id="myspan"> whatever</span></span>` with the pseudo element on the `.asterisk` span. However, this really should be handled with JavaScript.

Comment: Note that the asker didn't ask for no-javascript solution, just a no-jQuery solution.

Comment: The nested spans just might work in this case. Thanks bookcasey!

Comment: "And display is inherited." -- that is an oversimplification. I suggest "And display:none hides the element including all children."

Comment: Why does this answer have so many upvotes? It starts with "No, it is not possible." while there are at least 3 different ways how to achieve the goal in the other answers.

Answer (score 19):

I think a very easy approach to doing this is to exploit the *visibility* property. But note that a "hidden" element **still takes up the space**. But if you are okay with that, just make make the parent element "hidden" and pseudo element "visible":

```
#myspan        {visibility:hidden}
#myspan: after {visibility:visible}
```

Once you have the visibility taken care of, feel free to play around with the position so that excess space is avoided.

Something like,

```
myspan {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

myspan:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Very cool solution. Although I believe you meant to write `myspan:after { visibility: visible; ...`

Comment: @JonF. Thanks! Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 12):

It's definitely possible. Use `font-size: 0px` instead of `display: none`:

```
#myspan {
    /* display: none; */
    font-size: 0px;
}

#myspan:after {
    /* display: inline; */
    font-size: 16px;
    content: "*"
}
```

[A demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/bardirian/nzgxLwzg/).

In this case you can only use px/pt for the display text font units.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
#myspan       {font-size:0}
#myspan:after {font-size:16px; content:"*"}
```

If you have a min-font size specified, it won't work (browser setting). I'd only use this method for things like previous and next buttons so that screen readers will read "Previous", but you want to replace it with a \276e. So plan for what it will look like *with* the text showing up.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @bookcasey, setting `display: none` on an element unavoidably hides the `:after` or `:before` pseudo-element too (because they are not really something displayed after or before an element but content added *inside* the element, after or before its real content).

But the goal of *replacing* an element’s real content by generated content is in principle possible, according to the old (2003) [CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/) draft, by simply setting `content` on the element, e.g.

```
#myspan { content: "*"; }
```

So far, only Opera supports this. But a special case where the replacing content is an image is supported by WebKit browsers, too:

```
#myspan { content: url(asterisk.png); }
```

Comment: And now, nearly 8 years later?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you need to use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`.

See the answers in the following question for more detail:
*[How can I replace text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-through-css)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to break them into multiple content DIV blocks because the style is inherited by child elements. So it's not possible once the parent display style is defined.