# CSS counter on hidden submenu

Tags: css, menu, counter, css-counter

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu using nested `<ul>`,  every `<li>` displaying a number generated with CSS Counters.

Sub-menus are hidden with `display:none` when not hovered.

My problem is that counters are not incremented when an element has `display` set to `none`.

Do you know a CSS property to prevent this?

If I replace `display: none` by `visibility: hidden`, it's working but I'm not sure if it's nice to use this for my menu, are there any traps?

Comment: show some code what have you tried. A fiddle will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe change the `height` instead of the `display` property?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049423/in-css-use-displaynone-on-the-element-but-keep-its-after

Comment: `font-size: 0px;` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qdcqtocc/)?

Comment: @Harry Or a bit more [complex version](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/qdcqtocc/1/): `font: 0/0 a; visibility: hidden;`

Comment: @Harry, in fact it's already working with visibility:hidden alone. I just want to be sure that I will not have unwanted side effect by using this instead of display.

Comment: @FC': Visibility would also work but it would leave a space equivalent to the height of one line which can be avoided by using the font/font-size methods.

Comment: Ok. I don"t think it's useful in this case because submenus's position is absolute, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Harry, I mean it's already perfect with only visibility, because submenus are out of the flow. But if they were not, I would use that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mimick the `display: none` (hidden) behavior by setting the `font-size` to 0px and this would make the element be counted by the counter property.

```
.hidden{
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qdcqtocc/)

---

Or, a bit more complex version of the above (mentioned by [Hashem Qolami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725764/hashem-qolami) in comments)

```
.hidden{
    font: 0/0 a; 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/qdcqtocc/1/)

---

**Note:** `visibility: hidden` would also work but it would leave a space equivalent to the height of one line in the output.

[**Demo using Visibility Property**](http://jsfiddle.net/qdcqtocc/2/)

Comment: Thanks you and also Hashem