# I wish to load certain Divs with the proper text blocks, and audio files, specific to the page being viewed

Tags: css, image, text, load, external

This is so simple with graphics.  I have an 'external' CSS file that simply lists the graphics for two different positions on each web page.  Each page's containers are individually numbered (i.e., ID=upper6, lower6, upper7 and so forth).  The external CSS file (imageref.css) merely has a list: `#upper6 {background:url(path to graphic) no-repeat;)` etc.

These load just fine.

Why can't I do this with blocks of text (i.e., #uppercaption6, #lowercaption6).  I've tried every permutation I can think of (backgrounds, etc.).

I'd like to do the same to populate audio clips on each page.  Do I have to learn jQuery?  Help a rank beginner out here will ya?

Per request, I've expanded my dilemma thusly:

On the page/s in question, I initially load the CSS, and a text file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/stylesheet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/imageref.css" />
```

The second file could just be text, as it is formatted like this:

```
#upper6 {background:url(../images/phone.png) no-repeat right 0px;}
#lower6 {background:url(../images/writing_utensils.png) no-repeat right 0px;}
```

.
.
.

The image links listed there are called from this point in the HTML:

```
<figure id="photo_1"><a href="javascript:" onclick="upvis();" >
    <div class="figure_photo" id="upper6"></div></a></figure>
```

and all web pages work just fine.

Question:  How can I do the same thing with video clips and blocks of text?

These areas have the same type of lists, but do NOT work.

```
<video class="video-container" preload="none" controls>
    <source class="vid_mp4" id="vid01" />
</video>
```

or,

```
<div class="CC_container">
    <div class="closed_caption" id="caption1" ></div>
</div>
```

I'm confused that I can easily call in graphics and photos by referencing their "ID", but not video clips or blocks of text.

Comment: Could you give some code please?

Answer (score 0):

That can be done using 'content' property.

For instance, you can do :

```
<div class="CC_container">
<div class="closed_caption" id="caption1" >your dynamic text here: </div>
</div>

.closed_caption:after {
    content : " some text";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpdhT/)

Please let me know if it worked out well.

Comment: This will work if I wish to have a separate stylesheet for each page in the website.  What I would like to do is give each element an ID that will access an external list (of URL's?) like I have with the graphics.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean. If the text is stored somewhere else, then you have to use javascript. And it's the same for video clips.

Comment: Why don't I have to use javascript for the images?  I call them from a CSS (text) file simply by referencing their ID.  Just as I've shown above.  It's a simple list of ID's, with their background method as a URL to the file in the image directory.  I envision the same thing with video/audio clips and blocks of closed captioning text.  That way I can edit entire sites (this is training related) by merely editing a single page!

Comment: because images can set as background with CSS. But you cannot edit your HTML content with CSS, excepted with 'content' property as I said. That thread may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-through-css