# IE10: 'visibility:visible' on before pseudo-element of 'visibility:hidden' element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, visibility, pseudo-element

I have made a `DIV` with `visibility: hidden` and attached a `::before` pseudo-element of this DIV with `visibility: visible`. This works as expected in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but in Internet Explorer 10 the pseudo-element does not render.

Please explain if I'm accomplishing this wrong, or whether this is an issue with Internet Explorer. Are there any work arounds (we only have access to the CSS, not the source HTML)?

[JSFiddle demonstrating issue](http://jsfiddle.net/qrrw6/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Filters don't work on pseudo elements in IE.
Read:
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304078%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Other specified styling properties apply to the appearance of the inserted content, not to the element's content.
```

IE sucks, deal with it. 
I think the only way is to change the "hidden text" color to your background color, *and you know the rest...*

Comment: I agree that you have to just deal with it, but as far as I can tell IE is doing it wrong. Even that statement you're quoting doesn't make it clear that nested visibility won't work. The "Other specified styling properties" would be my visibility: visible on the pseudo element, which should be applied to the inserted content... but it isn't.