# Display one letter as another in page while copying untransformed text

Tags: html, css

In CSS, `.someclass { text-transform: uppercase }` translates all text with class `someclass` to uppercase, but when I select the text, copy, and paste into a text editor or e-mail, the letters retain their original case. Does some client-side web styling technology other than CSS let a document define a custom text transformation to change things other than case, such as `r` to `w` or `f` to `ꝼ`, without having the transformation applied when the user copies the text?

Answers to [Replace a particular character using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235800/replace-a-particular-character-using-css?lq=1) recommended JavaScript. I'd prefer to use some (non-CSS) declarative styling technology instead of script for a few reasons:

1. I want copy-and-paste to return the original text, not the transformed text, in the same way as the `text-transform` property.
2. I want "Find within page" (Ctrl+F) to work if the user types the untransformed letter.
3. I lack statistics on how many viewers of my site use NoScript or some other script whitelisting plug-in. But then skewed by the fact that I regularly visit an online forum whose users often brag about not being affected by a particular exploit because they don't run JavaScript
4. A script that runs `onload` will cause a noticeable flash of unstyled content as the lines are rewrapped.

Lately I was able to write an XSLT stylesheet to alter text nodes within the `<body>`, based on an [answer to a question about whitelisting characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5084382/2738262).
(Hint: `match="html:body//text()"` and `translate()`.)
It fails the copy and Ctrl+F criteria, and it [reportedly fails the no-FOUC criterion](http://www.altova.com/list/xsl-list/201001/msg1000308377.html) in browsers that try to get too clever, but it should load in just about every major browser since IE 6 even with script turned off.
However, a year ago, Google tried to [kill client-side XSLT a year ago by removing it from Blink](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/zIg2KC7PyH0[51-75-false]).
If Chrome, Opera, and other Chromium-based browsers end up dropping XSLT over this, no-XSLT users will probably outnumber no-script users.

Is acquiring a libre font and modifying it to include custom forms and ligatures that `@font-face`, `font-feature-settings`, and `font-variant-ligatures` can trigger the only way?

Comment: Using @font-face seems like the best solution. I tried breaking the sentence into 1-letter `span`s and then playing with `:before`, `width`, `text-indent` and `overflow` to hide the letter and display a question mark instead. It worked for hiding the message, but it is too dependent on the browser: Chrome & FF the copy-paste works perfectly (although FF doesn't highlight), IE copies text and `:before` making it ugly, Chrome allows search in a funky way, FF finds the strings but does not highlight them, IE finds only one character... you can find an example here http://jsfiddle.net/1jprubt1/

Comment: I know it's not a solution, but it could be a starting point for somebody with more CSS knowledge than me :$

Comment: There is no good way to do this with CSS.

Answer (score 3):

CSS - Cascade Style Sheets, as the name implies, it is used only to stylize the sheets (html pages). The snippet `.someclass { text-transform: uppercase }` is just stylizing the characters (alphabets) inside the tag with class `someclass`. Its not easy or can I say that its not possible to achieve your need using only CSS and not JavaScript.

According to [Zach Saucier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065702/)'s comment for your question, "There is no good way to do this with CSS", And I too agree that.

Using JavaScript its absolutely possible. But your criteria doesn't want you to do so.

My request to you, try using JavaScript or try not using CSS.