# How can I replace the text in an <h1> from a CSS file without using a <span> tag?

Tags: html, css, replace, styles

Here's what happening:

For my computer science class we're working on a project where we can only modify the CSS. I think it'd be super cool to change the content of the elements when you plug in my CSS file. Since I can't add a  tag, I dont know how else can I do this.
Here's what I have:

```
<div>

  <h1>Is the makerspace door open?</h1>

</div>

<div>


  <p id="switch_txt">Checking...</p>

</div>


</body>
```

---

I've tried using ::before and ::after pseudo selectors but these selectors can't place elements in the content property. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: CSS alone can't absolutely change/alter your DOM structure. Their purpose is to just give a style to a document

Comment: Okay, so that's what you *have*. Now, what - *exactly* - do you want to *do* with it?

Comment: It might be an interesting exercise, but using CSS to change document content is not supercool; it is for most uses and purposes just pointlessly risky.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-through-css)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The pseudo element is a good approach to visually replace text or insert an image.

text-indent can be useful added to a float context for the pseudo element to hide any dom inline or inline-block content(such as text or image).

[**Example:**](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pvovNR)

HTML test

```
<h1>show me something else</h1>
```

CSS test

```
h1 {
  text-indent:-9999px;
}
h1:before {
  text-indent:0;
  content:'Here is something else !';
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: This solution is nicer than mine. :) i didnt see i can use text-indent 0 to get the after text back

Comment: @DerVampyr just a different approach , it works because of the float :) (the layout thingy bob ..)

Comment: Nowadays its better not to use float :)

Comment: @DerVampyr , this is why i tell the layout reason, the good practice is the good reason ;) ...

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to change your content, but it's actually not the common way to do it through CSS. I think the goal was just to style up your HTML with some CSS. But here is a Snippet which adds `Question:` before your text in `<h1>` tag.

```css
.container h1:before {
  content: "Question: ";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Is the makerspace door open?</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did i get it right, that you want to replace the text in the h1?

Try this approach.

HTML:

```
<h1>Is the makerspace door open?</h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1:after {
  content: "test";
  left: -95px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}
h1 {
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: 105px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
<div>
     <h1>Is the makerspace door open?</h1>

</div>
<div>
    <p id="switch_txt">Checking...</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1 {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}
h1:after {
    float: left;
    content:"Ultra Cool";
    visibility: visible;
}
#switch_txt {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ro80gx3p/)**