# How to swap text in div using css

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a data platform that has widget specific to the platform
I'm using a widget called map that displays a map and the **title** linked to the map in the database.
the map includes a div title:

```
<map>
<div class="title">Title</div>
other divs ..
</map>
```

When I code i don't have access to the div title because it's included in the widget.
I want to change the text of the title using css.

I looked at these examples:
[How can I replace text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-through-css)

And did:

1. First option

   .title{
      visibility:hidden
   }

   .title:after{

   ```
   content:"NewTitle" ;
   visibility:visible;
   ```

   }

But then "Title" is just hidden but still takes space so my "NewTitle" is not centered

2. Second option

   .title{
     text-indent: -9999px;
       line-height:0;
   }

   .title:before{

   ```
   text-indent:0;
   content:'Welcome Back!';
   display:block;
   line-height: initial;
   ```

   }

But then my NewTitle is not well displayed.

How can I do to just switch "Title" to "New title" in CSS or eventually in Javascript.

Thank you for your help

Edit: the beginning of the displayed page

[image]

Flexibilités etc... is the title

I dont have access to what is written below ods-map in the html code as the ods-map is a widget. I can only change the css.

Comment: margin-left: -272px with .title:after class didn't fix it?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript solution is the standard to do this:

```
$('.title').html("new title here"); // jquery
document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerHTML = "new title here" // pure JS
```

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qpq45Luc/1/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I put the javascript code between <script></script> in my html page but nothing changed.

Comment: can you post how you did this please?

Comment: I just wrote
<script>document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerHTML = "new title here"</script>
As a first line of my html page

Comment: even before <head>? can you update your question and post your complete relevant html?

Comment: I don't have access to the <head> part as I use a data platform where some parts are already by default. I updated my post with the html page as it appears

Comment: i cannot find the javascript there...i just see a <script> tag but not the scripts inside - which platform is this?

Comment: edit with the script in the ng-scope class

The platform is an open data platform

Comment: errors in the console? try `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script>`

Comment: and i am not sure...but maybe you need to put this tag below the `title` element - but i am not sure, maybe it also works this way

Comment: it still doesn't work, maybe i can't add javascript code in this platform but i doubt it. The platform code is built on AngularJS.

Comment: did you try to put it below the title element?

Comment: try to wrap document ready around it - `$( document ).ready(function() { .............. }`

Comment: So I wrote <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerHTML = "new title here"
 </script> but not success either

Comment: Is there not a way to just cancel the div title and create a new one with the same attributes and at the same place?

Comment: `$( document ).ready(function() {document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerHTML = "new title here";}) </script>`

Comment: let's continue this in the chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84813/morg-help

Comment: @morg - javascript will ultimately be best resolution if you can get a workaround.  If not, see my updated answer.  Use margin-left: -272px.

Comment: I'm on chat Messerbill

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not tagged with [css](/questions/tagged/css), your initial way of getting the text replaced was on the right track. You just need to explicitly set the `display:block;` on the pseudo-element. Then position the pseudo-element `absolute`ly and with same padding on both the `div` and the pseudo-element to keep similar appearance.

Something like this:

```css
div.title { 
    visibility: hidden; position: relative;
    padding: 4px; 
}

div.title::after {
    content: 'Replaced text';
    visibility: visible;
    display: block; position: absolute;
    padding: 4px; top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<map>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
</map>
```

However, note that this is still a hack. Javascript is better way of doing this as, the text will be in your control.

Comment: When i do that the text is not displayed but the space it used to take is still there so my new title is not at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hacky, but going off of your first attempt just add margin-left: -272px (depending on your title).  https://jsfiddle.net/jmser6yd/2/

```
.title
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.title:after
{  
  content: "New Title";
  visibility: visible;
  margin-left: -272px;
}
```

I still like a javascript / jQuery solution better, as @messerbill suggested

Comment: When i do that the text is not displayed but the space it used to take is still there so my new title is not at the right place.

Comment: With the full title, <br> and subtitle (or whatever that is) try margin-left: -272px.  This is a hack, but it sounds like you need to hack your way through those widgets.

Comment: Yes i pasted the answer because the same thing appears than with abhitalks suggestion! where should i put !important

Comment: if needed, like this:  "margin-left: -272px !important;".  After I read what your title was, it sounds like the "!important" may not be necessary, but the different margin.