# CSS - Active link change text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an accordion link (that expands the accordion)

I would like the text change depending on whether the link is active or not.. for example:

```
DEFAULT : "View all Comments"
ACTIVE : "Hide Comments"
```

I know I can use CSS to style the content colours, style, etc., but wondering if there is a way I can change the actual text in the link that is dependent on the link being active or not.

Comment: With pure css you can make the text to be a pseudo-element(`:before` or `:after`) and use the `content: 'View all Comments'` and change it on active. Else you can do it with javascript.

Comment: E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-through-css

Comment: Although you could use the `content` property in combination with `:before` or `:after` selector, but **I don't recommend to do this in CSS** - use JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.accordion-item::before { /* default text of the accordion item */
  content : "View all comment";
}

.accordion-item:focus:before { /* triggered when the accordion item is clicked/focused */
  content : "Hide Comments";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="accordion-item"></a>
```

Here is a sample of how to do this, assuming you will have several link that stands for each accordion items.

Note that you could have used the new HTML `data-*` attribute to kind of *automatize* the process in case you are generating the HTML before being interpreted through language such as *Php* or *JavaScript* like following :

Answer (score -1):

You can use pseudo element like this

```
<a class="toggleText"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.toggleText::after
{
    content:"View all Comments";
}
.toggleText:active::after
{
    content:"Hide Comments";
}
```

psuedo elements might not supported on old browsers you wish you want to support.

check support here:http://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Aafter

and for content : http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20Generated%20content%20for%20pseudo-elements

Comment: Bad idea to put human-readable strings in `:before` and `:after` elements.

Comment: @torazaburo can you explain why?

Comment: For one thing, it's not very localizable. More basically, it makes it harder to manage the UI--strings now have to be managed in two different places. Ideally, `content` is used for things like icons, spaces and the like.

Comment: Well i see your point, but it still depends on the developer on how he will organize his/her work. There is no such rule that says if you're doing uncommon things even if its working, it will still be wrong.

Comment: It is generally not considered best practice, as someone else already mentioned in a comment on the question. It's uncommon because it's not best practice.

Comment: Yes, for now. But if you want to be innovative, you create your own rules, don't just follow someone, especially programming languages evolves.

Comment: It's not innovative. It's bad practice.

Comment: well that's your opinion, I'm certain that there's no perfect answer for that. like what I've said it depends on developer on how he organize his things, as long as the code doesn't slow the application, doesn't cause a problem then its correct.

Comment: No, it's not my opinion. It's the consensus of experts.