# How do I substitute a string in CSS without breaking copy paste?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following code:

```
(lambda (x) (+ x 1))
```

I'd like to display it as follows, without changing what actually gets copy-pasted:

```
(λ (x) (+ x 1))
```

The aim is to achieve an effect to Emacs' `prettify-symbols-mode`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css) shows how to hide some text and display something else instead, but `display:none` elements are not copied, at least in Firefox.

In other words, **how can I display prettified source code listings, without breaking copy-paste?** Bonus points for pure HTML+CSS.

The best that I could come up with is the following:

```
/* CSS */
.lambda:after {
    content:"λ";
}
```

```
<!-- HTML -->
(<span>
   <span style="position:absolute;left:-3000px;">lambda</span>
   <span class="lambda"></span>
 </span> x (+ x 1))
```

Is that the right approach?

Comment: This works on Firefox but not on Chrome https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/138/

Answer (score 3):

This works in Chrome and Firefox:

```
.hide {
  color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
}

.lambda:after {
  content:"λ";
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb144kt1/1/)

Comment: Very nice! Experimenting with your example suggests that `position:absolute` works as well (instead of `display` + `width`). Do you have an opinion on what might be better?

Comment: With `position: absolute;` if you select it in Firefox, it covers out part of the visible text. Going with `width: 0` feels a bit better as you kind of want to squash the text to zero width. It's a bit of a hack either way, so whatever works :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option:

```css
.lambda {
  font-size: 0;
}
.lambda:after {
  content: "λ";
  font-size: 16px;
  /* reset font */
}
```

```html
(<span>
   <span class="lambda">lambda</span>
</span>x (+ x 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it a documented property that setting size to 0 will "hide" an element? Or will some browsers have a minimum size?

Comment: It's not hiding the element, just the text within it. I'm not aware of any specific issues with a minimum size except *possibly* some really old version of Android.

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS content 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/) draft proposes that [`content`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-content-3/#inserting-replacing-content) should apply to elements too. Then, if browsers decide to implement this behavior, you will be able to use

```css
.lambda {
  content: "λ";
}
```

```html
(<span>
  <span class="lambda">lambda</span>
</span>x (+ x 1))
```

Comment: Indeed, that would be quite nice

Comment: Does the draft specify copy-paste behaviours, though? I can't see that in there.

Comment: @Clément No, but currently browsers only select DOM content. I think the CSS WG is considering adding some way to enable the selection of generated content in pseudo-elements, not sure how that will interact with `content` used on an element.

Comment: Is this really true? Edge on Windows phone does select content on pseudo-elements. I don't know about Edge in Windows though.

Comment: @Clément My comment was based on [a quote](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Nov/0294.html) of Florian (invited expert of W3C): "*By default (as per the legacy behavior), generated content in pseudo elements is not searchable/copyable/selectable*". But true, on Edge you can select and copy generated content of pseudo-elements. This affects the other answers to your question too.