# Change Text On Hover with CSS, Also Style That Text

Tags: html, css

Been stuck on this for ages, tried going to every link on first page of Google after searching "css change text on hover", no luck though.

I have text in the middle of a div, that text has it's own div which is styling the text and deciding the text position.

However I want the text to change when you hover over the div it is in and with CSS.

I've read guides of content/:before/:after but it made it much more confusing.

Here's the current code that does its current job fine:

```
/* Circles in the services section*/
.servicecircle { 
width: 204px; 
height: 204px;
background-image: url('/anonymous/for/reasons.png');
display: inline-block;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-left: 22px;
margin-right: 22px;
/* Button transition*/
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;
}

.servicecircle:hover{
background-image: url('/anonymous/for/reasons.png');
cursor: pointer;
}
```

I DID manage to get the text changing with the below code, however the divs were no longer aligned properly and I looked everywhere but found no way of styling the text within content.

```
/* Circles in the services section*/
.servicecircle:after { 
width: 204px; 
height: 204px;
background-image: url('/anonymous/for/reasons.png');
display: inline-block;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-left: 22px;
margin-right: 22px;
/* Button transition*/
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;
/* Content is inserted */
content: 'Service 1';
}

/* Changes content on hover */
.servicecircle:hover:after{
background-image: url('/anonymous/for/reasons.png');
cursor: pointer;
content: 'Service Description..';
}
```

This entire thing is inserted into the page with

```
<div class="servicecircle">                                 
 </div>
```

Is what I'm after even possible CSS?

P.S
If possible a link to a good guide would be great, I'm still fairly new to CSS so this might be a bit out of my league. All guides I've read use code I've never even seen before

Comment: Look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rejx1g5s/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace text with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css)

Comment: @GermanoPlebani Thanks man that works. However I want to learn how to do it myself, I'm struggling to see why I need CSS divs in twice, both with and without :after

Comment: The second is only for the style and content of pseudo element. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/89j1xne2/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS.

```css
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    div#line1 span#a {
        display:inline;
    }
    div#line1:hover span#a {
        display:none;
    }
    div#line1 span#b {
        display:none;
    }
    div#line1:hover span#b {
        display:inline;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="line1">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>  
            <td>
                <span id="a">this is sick</span><span id="b">this is awesome</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<div id="line1">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>  
            <td><span id="a">this is sick</span><span id="b">this is awesome</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style anything you want under your `.servicecircle:hover:after`
Just like this:

```
.servicecircle:hover:after{
background-image: url('/anonymous/for/reasons.png');
cursor: pointer;
content: 'Service Description..';
color:red; // Your own style #1
font-family: cursive; // #2
border: 1px solid black; // #3
width:100%; // #4
height: 30px; // #5
}
```

This [guide](https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/) will help you.

To center your text, Update this

```
.servicecircle:after { 
width: 204px; 
height: 204px;
background-image: url('/anonymous/for/reasons.png');
display: inline-block;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-content: center;
/* Button transition*/
-o-transition:.5s;
-ms-transition:.5s;
-moz-transition:.5s;
-webkit-transition:.5s;
transition:.5s;
/* Content is inserted */
content: 'Service 1';
}
```

Follow this [Centering Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: I need the text to be aligned in the center of the div though, if I put some margins in there it'd go for the whole div rather than the text :L

Comment: @Ben First, remove the `margin-left` and `margin-right` from your `.servicecircle:after`
Then, Add `display: flex;` `justify-content: center;` `align-content: center;` and the text will be centered. Follow this [Centering Guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) . I've updated the answer.