# Change content in a Strong tag into a class

Tags: css

I'm trying to change a strong content that is in a class.

If I try this code, it inserts the text after original text correctly:

```
.categoria-paginas a strong:after
{
    content: 'Schmitz';
}
```

But when I try to change all the content, it doesn't work:

```
.categoria-paginas a strong
{
    content: 'Schmitz';
}
```

Comment: `:content` only works with `:before` and `:after`

Comment: @j08691 is there some way to change the original content from css?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I set visibility to hidden and the new text to visible, it work:

```
.categoria-paginas a strong
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.categoria-paginas a strong:after
{
    content: 'Schmitz';
    visibility: visible;
}
```