# How to assign values or string to p tag through CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to assign values or string to `p` tag through CSS?

I am trying like this, why I am doing like this because I come from Android programming.

HTML file:

`<p> </p>`

CSS file:

```
p{
    text:"today"
}

result should= "today" in browser
```

So please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css

Comment: You cannot guess that there is a "text" CSS property, there isn't.

Comment: thx bro something is working ,i do not know why other people giving -2 vote they are selfish

Comment: @andy i know,but it is there in android and how to do in css, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)It is not possible in css,

2)Use jQuery or

```
$("p").html("today");
```

3)Use JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByTagName("P")[0].innerHTML = "Today";
```

note [0] is the index

Comment: if you use like this p:before{
    content: "today";
    color: black;
} if you have alreday text in <p>hi</p> then your output is= hi today

Answer (score 3):

Although I can't see a reason why you can't just add the text to the HTML file, I will still answer your question.

There is no way to add text inside of the HTML tag. The only way that you can add text around HTML is through pseudo elements like the following:

```
p:before{
    content: "today";
    color: black;
}
```

This is not recommended however, due to the fact that the text won't actually exist in the html and will need to be styled to display properly.

A much better solution would be to use javascript

```
<script>
     document.getElementById('todayTag').innerHTML = "today";
</script>
```

The 'todayTag' refers to an ID that will be placed on the p tag.

Comment: my one static html file has more css files based on some condition,it should be dynamic ,any way you give some good answer i like it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that via css alone, use javascript for that instead.

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "text";
```

```html
<p id="demo">

</p>
```

Comment: my one static html file has more css files based on some condition,it should be dynamic ,any way you give some good answer i like it