# Changing button text on hover

Tags: html, css, mousehover

I'm trying to change the text of the button when you hover on it, I found a solution but for some reason it won't work.

What I want to happen is when I hover on it it will turn to green and change the text to `Completed!`.

Currently the button changes color when I hover on it but the text wont change.

Here's my css:

```css
.button {
     border: 0px solid #004B84;
     background: red;
     padding: 3px 21px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
     -moz-border-radius: 16px;
     border-radius: 16px;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-family: Questrial;
     text-decoration: none;
     vertical-align: middle;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
   
   .button:hover {
     border: 0px solid #1292e1;
     background: green;
     color: white !important;
     content: "Completed!" !important;
    }
   
   .button:active {
     background: #1292e1;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none !important; 
    }
```

```html
<button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value="">New Request</button>
```

And here's the html for the button:

`<button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value="">New Request</button>`

Answer (score 8):

You could do this using a psuedo element.

```css
.button {
  width: 150px; /* set a width so it doesnt change upon hover */
   border: 0px solid #004B84;
   background: red;
   padding: 3px 21px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
   -moz-border-radius: 16px;
   border-radius: 16px;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: Questrial;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.button:hover span {
  display:none
}

.button:hover:before {
  content:"Completed!";
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
 <span>New request</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Doing this right now, Is there a way for the size of the button to not change when I hover on it?

Comment: Set a width and it will remain the same :)

Answer (score 7):

### CSS (without HTML):

You don't need to touch your HTML (manually adding `<span>` tags, manually 
 removing HTML element content, etc) for this.

Just set the button's text content `font-size` to `0px` then add your own text and font-size to the button using `:hover`, `::after` and `::after:hover`.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of using just CSS to edit your button's content:

```css
.button {font-size: 0px;min-width: 100px;min-height: 22px;}
.button::after {font-size: 14px;}

.button::after {
content: "New Request";
}
.button:hover::after {
 content: "Completed!";
}

.button:hover {
background-color: green;
border: 0px solid #1292e1;
color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value="">New Request</button>
```

### JavaScript:

Just use the [textContent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property to change your text on hover (`mouseover`) to **`Completed`** and back to **`New Request`** when hovered out (`mouseout`).

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of the JavaScript approach above:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector(".button");

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  this.textContent = "Completed!";
})
btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  this.textContent = "New Request";
})
```

```css
.button {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 22px;
}

.button:hover {
background-color: green;
border: 0px solid #1292e1;
color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value="">New Request</button>
```

Comment: I like this solution since it provides both the `CSS` and `JS` solution

Answer (score 4):

@K. Rogers Try Code Hope This Will Work For You!

```css
    /* .button */
    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      border: 0px solid #004B84;
      background: red;
      padding: 8px 25px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
      -moz-border-radius: 16px;
      border-radius: 16px;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 12px;
      font-family: Questrial;
      text-decoration: none;
      vertical-align: middle;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .button:hover { background: green; }
    .button span {
        transition: 0.6s;
        transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    .button:before,
    .button:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0.67em;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: .4s,opacity .6s;
    }

    /* :before */
    .button:before {
        content: attr(data-hover);
        transform: translate(-150%,0);
    }
    /* :after */
    .button:after {
      content: attr(data-active);
      transform: translate(150%,0);
    }
    /* Span on :hover and :active */
    .button:hover span,
    .button:active span {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0.3);
    }
    /* :before pseudo-element on :hover 
        and :after pseudo-element on :active */
    .button:hover:before,
    .button:active:after {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0,0);
        transition-delay: .4s;
    }
    .button:active:before {
        transform: translate(-150%,0);
        transition-delay: 0s;
    }
```

```html
   <button class="button" type="button" data-hover="COMPLETED" data-active="I'M ACTIVE"><span>New Request </span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution wit no change button html-code. Just using css style of pseudo-element `::after`
To prevent a change of button width on hover you need to define `width` property.

```css
.button {
     border: 0px solid #004B84;
     min-width: 150px;
     background: red;
     padding: 5px 21px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
     -moz-border-radius: 16px;
     border-radius: 16px;
     color: #ffffff;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-family: Questrial;
     text-decoration: none;
     vertical-align: middle;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     }
   .button:hover {
      background: green;
   }
   .button::after {
      content: "New request!";
    }
    
    .button:hover::after {
       content: "Completed!";
    }
   
   .button:active {
     background: #1292e1;
    }
    .button:active::after {
      background: #1292e1;
    }
```

```html
<button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value=""></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

See:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

> The content property is used with the ::before and ::after
>   pseudo-elements, to insert generated content.

You will need Javascript or more.

e.g.

```
<button class="button" type="submit" name="completed" value="" onmouseover="document.getElementsByName('completed')[0].innerHTML ='Completed!';" onmouseleave="document.getElementsByName('completed')[0].innerHTML ='New Request';">New Request</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

If you want to change the value of an element on a page, then you need to do it per code - try to do it with JavaScript

Edit: 
Seems like there is a way:

[How can I replace text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css)

Comment: Is there any way to do it using css?

Comment: Sure, you could use JS, but you can do it with just css.