# Using the abbr element for responsive text change with CSS

Tags: html, css, accessibility, responsive

I have the task to display an abbreviation on small screen and the full term on a large screen (e.g. "CSS" on small, "Cascading Style Sheets" on big screens).

I can easily do it by outputting both terms, each with a class and `display:none` one of them depending on media queries.

I was asking myself if I can use the `abbr` element to do it in a better way using this markup:

`<abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>`

Below you can see how for I've got with the `attr()` CSS property and that it's not rendering properly. My problem is that the `abbr` would somehow needed to be stretched out to fit in the long term. Is there a way to do this with CSS?

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  abbr {
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
  }
  abbr::before {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    text-indent: 9999px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
    I'm using 
    <abbr title="Cascasing Style Sheets"> CSS </abbr> 
    for responsive text changes.
</p>
```

https://codepen.io/smichaelsen/pen/VwYeZQZ

Comment: There is already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css though I don't think solutions there would work for you, maybe [a font-size hack](https://jsfiddle.net/4thxc5mn/) could be acceptable, and I'm pretty sure there is another Q/A with such an hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to put an span inside the `abbr` so that you have something you can select with the CSS to hide. That would look something like this:

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  abbr {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  abbr span {
    display: none;
  }
  abbr::before {
    content: attr(title);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  I'm using
  <abbr title="Cascasing Style Sheets"> <span>CSS<span> </abbr> for responsive text changes.
</p>
```

Alternatively, you could set the `font-size` of `abbr` to 0. This has the advantage of not needing any extra `span`s but it does mean you have to explicitly set the `font-size` of `abbr::before`. This seems like it's more likely to cause headaches down the line but it does work pretty cleanly.

For this I also added a blank space to the end of the `content` since setting the `font-size` to 0 effective removes the space after the `::before`.

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  abbr {
    font-size: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  abbr::before {
    content: attr(title) " ";
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  I'm using
  <abbr title="Cascasing Style Sheets"> CSS </abbr> for responsive text changes.
</p>
```

Side note: I added `text-decoration: none;` to both examples since once you've expanded the abbr you don't really want it to look like an abbreviation.