# How to replace ^foo by ^bar in a CSS tag?

Tags: css

How to replace `^foo` by `^bar` in a CSS tag ?

For instance, I have `<p>foo Hello World!</p>`, is it possible to replace it by `<p>bar Hello World!</p>` using CSS only (without javascript) ?

What I'd like is actually to automatically replace the first line by the second one,    becoming `→` :

```
<p>  Hello World!</p>
<p>→ Hello World!</p>
```

With the arrow `→`  set like this:

```
{
  content: "→ ";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:#DD4C4F;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: " For instance, I have <p>foo Hello World!</p>, is it possible to replace it by <p>bar Hello World!</p> using CSS " 
what would be the trigger for the change?

Comment: @Emm Actually, I was thinking about `text-replace` property, but it doesn't exist. I guess I should remove this post then.

Comment: To my knowledge you can not replace a part of the text purely with css (the shown solutions here only prepend text to your element). That being said you can ["replace" the whole text using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the element selector before the class. Also, remember that a space between the element and class means that the element contains the class. You probably want the element *with* the class.

Example:

```css
p.text::before {
  content: "→ ";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #DD4C4F;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">
  Hello World
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.my-class p::before {
  content: "→ ";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:#DD4C4F;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.my-class-using-hover p::before {
  content: " ";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:#DD4C4F;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.my-class-using-hover p:hover::before {
  content: "→ ";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  color:#DD4C4F;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class-using-hover">
  <p>Hover on me!</p>
</div>

<div class="my-class">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```