# Can I change the portfolio default pagination of Divi / Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, portfolio, divi

I'm building a website with Divi theme in Wordpress. I want to change the "previous" and "next" words of the portfolio pagination for a "<<" and ">>" arrows. I've tried with the wp-pagenavi plugin but is not working.

Is there any way to do that with php in the functions.php of the child theme?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Css, just add it to your Custom CSS block in Divi > Theme options.

Search for the Css Style inspecting the element in Chrome and use this code:

```
button {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

button:before {
  content: "<<";
  visibility: visible;
}
```

button should be replaced with the Css style of the button you are changing.

Based on this answer of another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17160267/10510941

Comment: Hi Fran. Thanks for your answer. I finally made it with a script but your proposal is better, I'll apply it!!

Comment: Awesome! Good luck!