# How to replace a a <p> element only with CSS (other methods won't work)

Tags: css

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css) question, but it didn't work for me.

Here is a picture of the situation:
[image]

I want to replace the text "Select subscription plan" with "All plans comes with a 7-day free trial." And I almost accomplished this using the following CSS:

```
.discourse-subscriptions-section-columns .section-column div > p:after {
content: "All plans come with a 7-day free trial!"; }
```

But then original text still remains, and if I use

```
.discourse-subscriptions-section-columns .section-column div > p {
visibility: hidden; }
```

then EVERYTHING disappears, not just the "Select subscription plan" part. Hence, I am not sure what to do to get this to work...

Comment: That's a weird question. Watch out for browser compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the `font-size` of the parent is `0px` so the `:after` can replace it. This will avoid using absolute positioning and make the text naturally fit in.

```css
p{
    font-size: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

p:after{
    content: "All plans come with a 7-day free trial!";
    position: relative;
    visibility: visible;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, optio?</p>
```

Comment: Nice! This works... Mostly at least. It replaces the text, but now there is barely a gap between this text and the buttons, so it looks kind of weird. How can I get the correct spacing back, to where there is a one-line gap between the <p> and the buttons?

Comment: It's difficult to guide you without taking a look at it. Can you share the website link?