# Woocommerce edit the cart label (mini cart short code)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to translate manually a text from 'cart' to 'panier' !

Is there a way that doesn't broke anything (with css ? Php ?)
I can't manage either with the CSS of the php (`function{$translate}`) the label of the cart button :

[image]

I can only change de HTML directly from the inspector :

[image]

Is there a way i can change that by css ? (i tried the content: `'Panier'!important` code with all the division, but nothing works...

Comment: Why do you want to change with only CSS? There are some hacky ways to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css)

Comment: Well actually, my goal is just to change the 'cart' label and i don't know where to change that ...  ! The article that you show isn't a real solution, cause i could just replace the shortcde by a text and a link

Answer (score 1):

In best case this should be translated via translation files `.po`, which are default translations in WP, and WooCommerce also use them.

In some custom solutions you should be able to filter some part of the code to re-render it in your way. This screenshot which you provide tell us nothing. You should provide source code which render this HTML, like WC template