# Right way to change mkdocs markdown toc title "table of contents"?

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

I'm using mkdocs with material layout and [toc markdown extension](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/toc/) for adding a toc to the right for a documentation project.

I use [up42's wiki](https://sdk.up42.com/authentication/) as a template for my wiki. I would like to change the title "Table of contents".

[image: Table of contents]

The [toc markdown documentation](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/toc/#usage) provides a parameter "title" that doesn't change anything when used in my `mkdocs.yml`:

```yaml
markdown_extensions:
  - markdown.extensions.toc:
      baselevel: 1
      permalink: true
      title: "SOMETITLE"
```

Does anyone have a clue which parameter to use or how to change the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature was added in Material for MkDocs [7.3.5](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/changelog/#7.3.5) (which you are using as can be inferred from the screenshot). The syntax is exactly as you specified in your original post:

```yaml
markdown_extensions:
  - toc:
      title: On this page
```

For further guidance please refer to [the documentation](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/setup/extensions/python-markdown/#toc-title).

Answer (score 0):

### Using CSS

I didn't find the right parameter or the problem yet, but a simple CSS overset does the job pretty well (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14261898/13083583)):

```css
.md-nav__title {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.md-nav__title:after {
  visibility: visible;
  content: 'SOMETITLE';
  display: block;
}
```