# Is there any way to replace div content by CSS

Tags: css

Is there any way to change the div content by CSS, I want to replace div text by the nth-child method in CSS, I tried

```css
.member-info .mb-meta span:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}

.member-info .mb-meta span:nth-child(1):after {
  content: 'Speciality123';
}

.member-info .mb-meta span:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}

.member-info .mb-meta span:nth-child(2):after {
  content: 'Designation123';
}
```

```html
<div class="member-info">
  <h3>sometext</h3>
  <div class="mb-meta">
    <span>Speciality: </span>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-meta">
    <span>Designation: </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css)

Comment: @KiranMistry i tried this in here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like that ?

```css
.member-info .mb-meta span:nth-child(1) {
  display: none;
}

.member-info .mb-meta:nth-child(2):after {
  content: 'Speciality123';
}

.member-info .mb-meta span:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}

.member-info .mb-meta:nth-child(3):after {
  content: 'Designation123';
}
```

```html
<div class="member-info">
  <h3>sometext</h3>
  <div class="mb-meta">
    <span>Speciality: </span>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-meta">
    <span>Designation: </span>
  </div>
</div>
```