# How to use CSS to replace text?

Tags: html, css

How do I replace `Type：` with `Class：` using CSS?

```
<span class="skills">Type：<a href="....../type/aaa/">aaa</a>, <a href="...../type/bbb/">bbb</a></span>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896402/how-can-i-replace-text-with-css

Comment: Can't solve my problem, mine has the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.skills{font-size:0;}
.skills a{font-size:20px;}
.skills a:after {content: ", "; font-size: 20px;}
.skills a:last-child:after {content: ""; } 
.skills:before {
content: 'Class: ';
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<span class="skills">Type：<a href="....../type/aaa/">aaa</a>, <a href="...../type/bbb/">bbb</a></span>
```

Comment: You have changed HTML structure (moved `,` inside tag)

Answer (score 2):

It's was challenging without updating HTML here's code 
It's not perfect but it's works :D

```css
.skills:before {
  content: "Class: ";
  font-size: 14px;

}

.skills {
  font-size: 0;
}
 
.skills a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.skills a:after {
  content: ", ";
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<span class="skills">Type：<a href="....../type/aaa/">aaa</a>, <a href="...../type/bbb/">bbb</a></span>
```