# how can I add only ellipsis and remove original text

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to make breadcrumbs that looks like

[image]

My final goal is
`Item1/.../.../Item4`

So I was able to make `Ite...` but I want to make it only `...` like example above. please provide code example(it helps me a lot since I am beginner in css/html) Thank you!

what I had tried..

```
//index.html
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
 <li class="breadcrumbs__item">Item 1</li>
 <li class="breadcrumbs__item">Item 2</li>
 <li class="breadcrumbs__item">Item 3</li>
 <li class="breadcrumbs__item">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

```
css

.breadcrumbs {
 &__item {
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: "[...]";// or ellipsis;
   max-width: 10px;
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
}
```

Comment: You should provide what you already have and where the issue is. This site is about helping people with their issues rather than a writing service where you can request what you need :)

Comment: sure let me edit this right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I found is by wrapping the items inside spans to hide them, according to [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13941481/17684809). You need it because you can't add `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements to a `display:none` element.

Then you can :

- `display:none` spans that are not the first and last items
- add `...` to the elements that are not the first and last items
- add `/` after every elements that are not the last one

note : `ul{font-size: 0;}` and `li{font-size: initial;}` are to remove some unecessary space

```css
ul{
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;    
  font-size: initial;
}

li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) span{
  display: none;
}
li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):before{
  content: "...";
}
li:not(:last-child):after{
  content: "/";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Item 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 3</span></li>
  <li><span>Item 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: love the solution @cedric