# How do i select all elements with a specific style-attribute?

Tags: jquery-selectors, selector

```
$('[style*="<style-attr>:<value>"]')
```

So i want to select every element with the same style-attribute to change them, but it won't work with that selector.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Css selector for elements with style attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426182/css-selector-for-elements-with-style-attribute)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your selector, can you post an example of what you have tried?

Comment: @jbutler483: Although similar, that was a selenium question.

Answer (score 0):

That selector checks if the style attribute is exactly that string, so it won't work if you have other things in the style attribute. It would be kind of inefficient, but you could loop through each element that you want to check, and for each one do:

```
if(<my-element>.css("<style:attr>") == "<value") {
//do stuff with the element
}
```