# attr as property in css selector

Tags: css, attr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS selector by style attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426882/css-selector-by-style-attribute)

html:

```
<div data-family='arial'></div>
```

in css i want to use this family value. Example:

```
div{font-family: attr(data-family)}
```

Family can be any string.
How make it work?

Comment: You realize that something like this will require really modern browsers?

Comment: @ʎǝɔɐɯ ǝlʎʞ: No, it's completely different.

Comment: This won't work in any browser because they currently only support `attr()` for the `content` property, and not others. For now, you'll need to hardcode the value in CSS, or use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
 div[data-weight="bold"]{
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3KZLX/)

Comment: Remove the space between `div` and `[`.

Comment: Removed from the code the space that given error

Comment: But still, attribute value is hardcoded here.. I doubt it's what OP wanted.

Comment: @Michal Klouda: Exactly, but there really isn't any other way. See my comment on the question.

Comment: data-weight is dynamic. I changed question.

Comment: @BoltClock I was just wondering why this was upvoted while not giving answer and I ended up downvoted ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you ask about in pure CSS. Using jQuery it could be done this way:

```
$.each($('div'), function(i, div) {
    $.each($(this).data(), function(key, val) {
        var realKey = key.replace(/([A-Z]{1})/g, '-$1').toLowerCase();
        $(div).css(realKey, val);
    })
})​
```

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8xupr/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
div[data-weight="bold"] { font-weight: bold; }
```

But I don't believe there's any way to use an attribute as a property without some JavaScript