# CSS: Can I target by element that has a border-right attribute?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to apply dividers to a Bootstrap tab component. Basically, I want horizontal dividers when the class is not active:

```
.nav-tabs > li:not(.active) a{
     border-right:1px solid #ddd;
     margin-right:0px; 
     border-radius:0;
}
```

This works except for the adjacent tab (next to the active one). This one doubles up the border.

Is there some trickery to allow me to test whether an element does not have a border-right or border-left property so I can assign one? Something like:

```
.nav-tabs > li:not(.active)[!border~]{}
```

Comment: Nope...none whatsoever. CSS is done by selecting **elements** not their styles.

Comment: Yes you could, but border-right in your case is not an attribute.

<div border-right="1"></div> can be targetted for sure!

Comment: Oh and I'm pretty sure that should be an easier solution than trying to "trick" around it.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of. If it's an inline style you can (again, kind of).

```
div[style="border-right:1px solid #ddd"]
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426882/css-selector-by-style-attribute). Duplicate question of [CSS selector by style attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426882/css-selector-by-style-attribute)