# Selecting based on style attribute in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

(How) is it possible to select elements based on their style attribute?

Thanks to the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426882/css-selector-by-style-attribute), we know it is impossible using pure css.

To enlight the issue, i give my concrete case: i want to change background color of all `p` and `span`s with background color white in a `div` to transparent.

Does angular some favor about it? Or what else can be used?

Comment: dont use jquery selectors at all. use angulars awesome feature directives

Comment: directives are write once use anywhere for anything

Comment: Why can't you use classes for this? Trying to parse colors from DOM returns different formats in different browsers. Provide more details about your specific issue

Comment: angular should not have selectors at all

Comment: since html files are external, i have no control about them @charlietfl And if i encapsulate them using a class, i still can't select the ones with a certain background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

[].slice.call(divs).forEach(function(div) {
  var color = window.getComputedStyle(div, null).backgroundColor;

  if (color === 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }
});
```

You'll need to normalize the colors since different browsers return it in different formats.

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ebq6manb/1/**

Comment: you should not use this in angularjs

Comment: @sundar why not? it seems it solves the problem although angularjs is not used. I have still no idea whether it can be solved using angular its "directives"

Comment: @Asqan you cant use anything to solve ur problem.so if you want to do in native way then why did u come to angularjs if you are going to use angular u should do it in angular's way.angular is not meant for doing this kind dom manipulations

Comment: @Asqan learn about angulars test driven system.and docs for reference

Comment: @sundar that's a silly statement ... angular is javascript

Comment: @charlietfl oh really man thanks for the update.read angular's test driven system and you'll accept my statement

Comment: @charlietfland also read about reusable components and why directives are being used in angular

Comment: @sundar nobody is saying this is being used in directive..that is the proper place to use it

Answer (score -1):

You could grab all the divs with a selector, iterate through them, use the `attr('style')` method and then do a check to see what background color they are.