# Using CSS Attribute Selectors to target the src of background-image

Tags: css

I am using using the background-image attribute to assign images to a range of `div` on my site. However, with `background-image` attributes, I also need to assign `background-size` to get it looking right.

This works fine mostly, but I need to change the `background-size` attribute based on the file type used in the `background-image` attribute. For example, as standard I want to user `background-size: cover;` but when the `background-image` is an SVG I want to use `background-size: auto;`

Is this possible using CSS attribute selectors? If not, any other solution?

**My attempt (SCSS):**

```
&.bg-image {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 500px;
    max-height: 700px;
    &[src$=".svg"] { background-size: auto; }
}
```

Comment: Your code is actually supposed to work as expected. What is the problem? Could you set up a snippet or fiddle?

Comment: You want to check the style attribute in css and add a rule. I don't think it's possible yet. This answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8426901/886539

Comment: @Tigran I don't think it's targeting the background-image attribute, which is where the SVG is. It's not part of the img src?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `background-image` is your only inline CSS property, you can do this:

```css
.bg-image {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 700px;
}

.bg-image[style^="background-image:"][style$=".svg)"] {
  background-size: 103px 94px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image" style="background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/80/Wikipedia-logo-v2.svg)"></div>
```

If `background-image`is not the only property but it is the last one, you can use this selector: `[style$=".svg)"]`.

Finally, the most general case, for any location of `background-image` in the style attribute use this selector: `[style*=".svg)"]`.

Even with the loosest selector: `[style*=".svg)"]` (or jpg, or png...) the only declaration the selector can possibly apply is the background-image.

The other approach is to add `data-type=svg` or what have you to the divs and then target them in CSS `[data-type=svg]`.

Or you could use `img` instead, as in your example.

Comment: Turns out, I have another inline CSS element. Presumably this means your approach won't work?

Comment: You can either move your other CSS rules to stylesheet or use just `[style$=".svg)"]` and make sure that background-image is at the end, or use `[style*=".svg)]"]`. After all even with `[style*=".svg)"]` (or jpg, or png...) the only declaration the selector can possibly apply is the background-image.

Comment: Ah, seem to have it working now &[style*=".svg"] { background-size: auto; }

Just a small tweak. Do you want to convert this to an answer and I can mark as accepted? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! I updated the answer to include the thoroughest list of available options and added a snippet.