# CSS not updating in IE / Edge?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr3d0eL3/1/)

I have a css rule depending on the display status of a neighbor:

```
#top:not([style*="display: none"]) + #bottom {
  color:red;
}
```

When I hide the '#top' div using javascript, the color changes since the css rule is no longer valid.
This is not the case in Internet Explorer and Edge ! Am I doing something wrong or is this just a bug in Microsofts browsers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid that approach, as [it's somewhat fragile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426901/1264804). Instead, explicitly toggle a class on a parent element or #top, and make your CSS changes based on that:

```
body.toggled #bottom {
  color:red;
}
body.toggled #top {
  display: none;
}

$("#btn").click(function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('toggled');
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/7aeqtaus/)