# javascript how do i find which elements contain a background image using the style attribute

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-selectors, styles, background-image

I am trying to add script to a web page that is generated as part of a go-daddy web site.

The image is presented in a div as a background image that was set using the style attribute.

```
style="background-image: url("//img1.wsimg.com/isteam/ip/c77f0810-0ea1-4425-b963-0e5820c70a3f/5a18a70f-82dc-45b6-bfb8-8f8e7ff1c875.jpg/:/cr=t:0%25,l:0%25,w:100%25,h:100%25/rs=w:1400,h:400,cg:true,m/cr=w:1400,h:400,ax:c,ay:c");"
```

The id of the div container is generated automatically and changes between runs.

Is there anyway I can find the elements on the page that have a background image set in the HTML style attribute using plain javascript ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426882/css-selector-by-inline-style-attribute might send you in the right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector by inline style attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426882/css-selector-by-inline-style-attribute)

Comment: This question is not the same @LGSon That post was about css and this is about javascript

Comment: @Savandy No, but the answer is, hence also being a duplicate.

Comment: @LGSon I don't get you, could you explain?

Comment: @Savandy For a question to be a duplicate, it doesn't have to be the same question. If a given answer can be applied to 2 different question, they are as well duplicates.

Comment: @LGSon But what does the other answer has to do with this question anyway? I don't get your point

Comment: This question can be solved with the duplicates answer, where one use the attribute selector to find an element, hence it is a duplicate.

Comment: Guys: @Savandys answer is helping me solve my problem. The refered answer does not display a javascript solution, it debates css selectors.  I can make sense of Savandys answer and it helps me.

Comment: Could you mark it?

Comment: @JulianPollak You just do like this with the dupe's answer: `var bkgimg = document.querySelector('[style*="img1.wsimg"]');` ... I do not recommend to choose the given answer and loop all elements like that.

Comment: @LGSon Thanks, I will check this option - please note that the refered css answer advises that this solution needs to know the exact bytes where as Savandy's answer even thought it is less efficiant is not dependant on the internal string.

Comment: @JulianPollak If you read up on what I suggested, you will find it is even better than looping, and does not need  to know the exact bytes

Comment: @LGSon I tried what you proposed and can not get it to work. The query returns empty. I appreciate your effort. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*")

for (var i = 0 ; i < elements.length ; i++) {
 if (elements[i].style.backgroundImage) {
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
    alert(elements[i].id + " has background image")
 }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ckrm2eLL

Comment: I have checked this answer and it answers the question. Unfortunatly some how go-daddy does not let this code execute as expected :-( . Thank you @Savandy. I don't think that your answer should have been down voted. Once i get a few more points I will upvote it