# Catch div which has class name and has css attribute with specific value

Tags: javascript

I use this code to add values that has class name. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4rpw3te/). I specifically want to add values of divs with class name `box` and has css attribute `display block`.

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
  sum += parseInt(test[i].textContent);
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Your code works, What is the problem?

Comment: I specifically want to add values of divs with class name box and has css attribute display block.

Comment: You already have the class name "box. "  Perhaps check for "box" and "block" classes with `document.querySelectorAll("div.box.block")`? `<div>` tags don't have values, but I believe `textContent` as you have, should work.. You can check each div's `style.display` while you're looping, but I'm not sure what it would be since the style is set by the class.

Comment: This already has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426901/943435

Comment: You can also use the `getComputedStyle` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle