# Can conditional CSS style be based on other CSS style?

Tags: css, checkbox

My checkboxes change label color when checked.  It's defined in my stylesheet like this:

```
:checked + label {color: white;}
```

However, some of my checkboxes have an outline style.

```
outline = "1px solid"
```

I want these outlined checkboxes to change to the color blue instead of white.

```
:checked (AND CHECKBOX HAS OUTLINE) + label {color: blue;}
```

Is there a way to do this in my stylesheet?

PS:
The outline was applied to specific checkboxes with a javascript function.

```
if (n !== -1) {
 document.getElementById(id).style.outline = "1px solid";}
```

Comment: how do you put the outline on _some_ of the checkboxes?

Comment: could you add some HTML so we can see what your markup looks like?  Better yet, create a create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Ejay.  Each checkbox has a unique ID and style.  Some of them are styled with the above outline code.  The HTML might complicate the matter as I only want to do this with the stylesheet.

Comment: Basically...no. CSS is based on selecting **elements** not styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to move the outline style into a class selector.

```css
.outline {
    outline: 1px solid;
}
:checked + label {
    color: red;
}
.outline:checked + label {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="outline"/><label>green</label>
<input type="checkbox"/><label>red</label>
```

Comment: I do not have class defined in any of my inputs.  Can the above javascript be changed to apply the style change and add a class="outline"?  I'm obviously new to this.

Comment: Got it. Just needed to add document.getElementById(id).className = "outline";

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dmbsqzkn/1/

The only way you can use CSS to select a style property is if style was declared inline. For instance

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" style="outline: '1px solid';"></input>
```

CSS:

```
input:checked[style="outline: '1px solid';"] + label
{
  color: blue;
}
```

obviously inline styles are frowned upon because they can muddle your code and make adjustments to styling at a later time a pain. That's the only way you can do it with CSS. It would most likely be easier and more correct to uniform to just apply a separate class to those elements.

Please see this post [Advanced CSS Selector - Select based on styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535193/advanced-css-selector-select-based-on-styling) for more info.

Comment: I added the outline in a javascript function.  I've edited the original post to reflect this code.  I couldn't get your solution to work, but it seems like we are close.